# Compare two canvas image (reference one and current on the website)

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I would like to compare two images. I wrote a piece of code, but the result shows that images are the same, although in fact image was changed. What I wanted achievied was, when I press 'o' key, I want to refreshing site every 5 seconds and compare image which is place in the website now with the image which was on the page when I set my interval (by pressing 'o' key). The images have the same size.

````
// @name         Nowy123
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://*/*
// @grant        none
// @include      *.*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    let intervalNum = localStorage.getItem('intervalNum');
    console.log(intervalNum);
    if(intervalNum){
        clearInterval(intervalNum);
        intervalNum = setInterval(specHero, 5000);
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
       if (event.keyCode === 79) {
           console.log("pressed o");
           console.log("interval started");

           //image
           let img = document.querySelector('.contentContainer').querySelector('.heroImage');
           var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
           var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
           canvas.width = img.width;
           canvas.height = img.height;
           context.drawImage(img, 0, 0 );
           var refImg = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
           localStorage.setItem('refImg',refImg);
           console.log(img);


           intervalNum = setInterval(specHero, 5000);
           localStorage.setItem('intervalNum', intervalNum);
       }
    });
    document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
       if (event.keyCode === 80) {
           console.log("pressed p");
           console.log("interval stopped");
           intervalNum = localStorage.getItem('intervalNum');
           clearInterval(intervalNum);
           window.localStorage.clear();
       }
    });

    function specHero(){
       let img = document.querySelector('.contentContainer').querySelector('.heroImage');
       var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
       var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       canvas.width = img.width;
       canvas.height = img.height;
       context.drawImage(img, 0, 0 );
       var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
       let refImg = localStorage.getItem('refImg');
       let result = isMatch(imgData, refImg);
       console.log(result);
       if(!result){
        console.log("Found difference");
           clearInterval(intervalNum);
           return;

       }
       location.reload();
    }

    function isMatch(data1,data2){
    for(var i = 0; i<data1.length; i++){
        if(data1[i] != data2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

})();```
````

Comment: So what do you suggest instead of localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check what is actually stored in `localStorage`. Spoiler alert: it's the string `"[object ImageData]"`.

`localStorage.setItem('refImg',refImg)` doesn't store the actual image data, it stores the string `"[object ImageData]"`. That's because `localStorage` can only store strings, and when you try to store a non-string value, that value will be converted into a string by calling `toString` on it. `toString` of image data objects return the string `"[object ImageData]"`.

Since you are working with image data objects (typically very large objects) and you want to constantly compare them, using `localStorage` (which uses the hard drive to store data) can lead to a hit in performance, besides, there isn't a straightforward way of storing the image data in `localStorage` anyway. I suggest you keep the objects stored in memory by using a (semi) global variable to hold the reference image data object like so:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  let refImageData; // this will hold the reference image data object instead of saving it to localStorage

  document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    /* ... */
    refImageData = refImg; // instead of localStorage.setItem('refImg',refImg)
    /* ... */
  }

  function specHero() {
    /* ... */
    let refImg = refImageData; // instead of let refImg = localStorage.getItem('refImg'), this is redundant anyway because refImageData is already accessible from the other functions
    /* ... */
  }
```

**Note:** as @Kaiido pointed out in a comment bellow, image data objects don't have a `length` property, they have a `data` property that holds the actual pixel data, so `isMatch` should be like this:

```
function isMatch(data1, data2) {
  for(let i = 0; i < data1.data.length; i++) {
    if(data1.data[i] != data2.data[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

**Edit - Saving the image data object to localStorage:**

If you must save the image data object to local storage, you need to convert the `data` property of the image data object (which is of type `Uint8ClampedArray`) into a regular array first using `Array.from`, and `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse` to convert that array into a string and back into an array. For that we use these two helper functions, one for saving and one for retrieving the `data` property of the image data object:

```
function saveImageData(key, imageData) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(Array.from(imageData.data)));
}

function loadImageData(key) {
    // it's probably a good idea to check if local storage has something saved before executing the following line of code
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
}
```

And use them to save/retrieve like so:

```
saveImageData("refImg", refImg);      // instead of localStorage.setItem('refImg',refImg)

let refImg = loadImageData("refImg"); // instead of let refImg = localStorage.getItem('refImg');
```

Note that this will save only the `data` array of the image data object and not the image data object itself. So `isMatch` should become:

```
function isMatch(data1, data2) {
  for(let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    if(data1[i] != data2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

When you call `isMatch` you have to pass only the `data` array of the image data object, like so:

```
isMatch(imgData.data, refImg);
// imgData is an actual image data object so we need to access its 'data' property
// refImg is the 'data' array saved to local storage, no need to access 'data' on it
```

Comment: The solution in the first paragraph is wrong. JSON.stringify( imageData )  will just create the `"{}"` string, not that usefll... What they want is the `.data` Uint8ClampedArray member. That's btw also why their `isMatch` function returned true here, the ImageData doesn't have a `.length` property and thus the loop is not even entered once.

Comment: @Kaiido Good point about `JSON.stringify`. It does, however, store the data and not just an empty `'{}'`, albeit not in a format that makes a whole lot of sense when it gets parsed back. As for the `isMatch` point, I've added a note to OP to fix that. I was so focused on the storage bit that I didn't even notice that. Thanks!

Comment: JSON.stringifying the Uint8ClampedArray in `.data` will keep the data (in an indexed object format), but on the ImageData like it was in the first revs it will just return `"{}"`.

Comment: The problem is that after refresh this global variable is erased. 
I have this info in console:
`Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at specHero`

Comment: That's exactly what I want to achieve. Thank You very much. I was trying to make a function which convert imaga data content into string, then use localStorage and compare strings to find the difference but it isn't work. One more time thank You!.

Comment: @marshall94pl You're welcome! I'm glad I could help. Happy coding :)